# Redirect the page to the login page if the user sits idle for some time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dns

When the web page is opened and left with out doing any operations then after some time I need to be redirected to the login page asking user to re-login again. How can I do that in asp.net mvc 3 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the user session variable is null or not,if it is null,then redirect to login page.

if (Session["User"] == null)
{  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: what u mean return to code? it will redirect to login page.page load of login screen will occur after redirecting.

Comment: After the session is completed will it redirect to the code that you given above. Where did i paste that code

Comment: Place it in your login page of page load event.

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc3 not asp.net